# Opening files from a folder using values stored in a range

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code to open a file that contains a number that is usually ten digits.

I would like the code to refer to my worksheet for that number rather than mentioning it in the code.

When I try the Range formula, it doesn't work because the number is too large to be stored as an integer. If I store this number as text, it's not able to locate the file.

```vb
Sub OpenFiles()
    
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim MyFile As String

    MyFolder = "H:\Test\" 'EXACT folder name containing the files. 
                          'Change to suit, but don't forget the trailing backslash '\'
    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*2964179000*.xlsm")
    
    Do Until MyFile = ""
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "" & MyFile
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `MyFolder` already ends with a backslash, so you don't need the backslash at the start of the file name. Something like `MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "*" & yourSheet.Range("A1").Value & "*.xlsm")` should work

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store long numbers on the sheet then format the cell(s) as Text before adding their content.

You should be able to do something like this:

```vb
Sub OpenFiles()
    
    Dim MyFolder As String, ws As Worksheet
    Dim MyFile As String
   
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Info") 'for example
    
    MyFolder = "H:\Test\"  
                          
    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "*" & ws.Range("A10").Value & "*.xlsm")
    
    Do Until MyFile = ""
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "" & MyFile
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop
    
End Sub
```